# Two errors when trying to run make command

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am trying to build Bitcoin Core on MacOs.
Followed instructions here https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md

When I run **make** command, I get these two errors

> 2 errors generated.
> make[2]: *** [libbitcoin_server_a-miner.o] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Tried **sudo make** but results are the same.

Bitcoin core version I'm working with is 0.15.0 (I know it's old but I'm trying to follow instructions from the 'Mastering Bitcoin' book)

EDIT : FULL ERROR

> In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp:17:
> /usr/local/include/boost/multi_index/detail/ord_index_impl.hpp:1253:26: error:
> no matching function for call to object of type 'const
> boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_implboost::multi_index::identity<CTxMemPoolModifiedEntry,
> CompareModifiedEntry, boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<2,
> CTxMemPoolModifiedEntry,
> boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<modifiedentry_iter,
> CompareCTxMemPoolIter, mpl_::na>,
> boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<ancestor_score,
> mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na,
> mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na,
> mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>,
> boost::multi_index::identity,
> CompareModifiedEntry>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na,
> mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na,
> mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>,
> std::**1::allocator >,
> boost::mpl::v_item<ancestor_score, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl*::na>, 0>,
> boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_non_unique_tag,
> boost::multi_index::detail::null_augment_policy>::key_compare' (aka 'const
> CompareModifiedEntry')
> return y==header()||!comp*(key(y->value()),key(v));
> ^~~~~
> ./miner.h:74:10: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type
> 'const
> boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_implboost::multi_index::identity<CTxMemPoolModifiedEntry,
> CompareModifiedEntry, boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<2,
> CTxMemPoolModifiedEntry,
> boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<modifiedentry_iter,
> CompareCTxMemPoolIter, mpl_::na>,
> boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<ancestor_score,
> mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na,
> mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na,
> mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>,
> boost::multi_index::identity,
> CompareModifiedEntry>, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na,
> mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na,
> mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>,
> std::_*1::allocator >,
> boost::mpl::v_item<ancestor_score, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl*::na>, 0>,
> boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_non_unique_tag,
> boost::multi_index::detail::null_augment_policy>::key_compare' (aka 'const
> CompareModifiedEntry'), but method is not marked const
> bool operator()(const CTxMemPoolModifiedEntry &a, const CTxMemPoolMo...
> ^
> 2 errors generated.
> make[2]: *** [libbitcoin_server_a-miner.o] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
> make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: This can't be the only error printed. Can you see any other error above?

Comment: @MCCCS Right. Editted the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/12009) caused by newer versions of Boost was later solved. You may either checkout v0.15.2 or download the 0.15.2 tagged source code [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/archive/v0.15.2.zip)

Comment: Tried it. Getting same errors. I only chose 0.15.0 because it's used in the book. Can I try latest version still understand what the book says? Is there a big difference?

Comment: @GugaTodua Yes, no, the build instructions haven't changed since